# Laravel : How create table depend on period between two dates

Tags: laravel, loops, laravel-blade, php-carbon

I have this controller which return two array and two variables, first array is daily count of students through period between two dates, second one names of students, and the variables is the two dates (from and to)

```
public function period(Request $req)
    {
        $daily = Absence::query()
            ->select('name', 'date')
            ->selectRaw('count(date) as counts')
            ->whereBetween('date', [$req->from, $req->to])
            ->where('stage',$req->stage)
            ->where('group',$req->group)
            ->groupBy('name', 'date')
            ->get();
  
        $students = Absence::select('name')
            ->whereBetween('date', [$req->from, $req->to])
            ->where('stage',$req->stage)
            ->where('group',$req->group)
            ->groupBy('name')
            ->orderBy('name')
            ->get();

        $arr['daily'] = $daily;
        $arr['from'] = $req->from;
        $arr['to'] = $req->to;
        $arr['students']=$students;
        
        return view('period',$arr,);
    }
```

Now in blade template I want to create table like this :
[image]

I made this blade template :

```
@php
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    $from = Carbon::parse($from);
    $to = Carbon::parse($to);
@endphp
    <div class="container text=right" dir="rtl">
        <table class="table" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>#</td>
                    <td>ناڤ</td>
                   @for ($i = $from; $i <= $to; $i->modify('+1 day'))
                        @php
                            $date =$i->format('m/d');
                        @endphp
                        <td>{{$date}}</td>
                       
                    @endfor
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @php
                    $counter=1;
                @endphp
                @foreach ($students as $student)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$counter}}</td>
                        <td>{{$student->name}}</td>
                        @for ($i = $from; $i <= $to; $i->modify('+1 day'))
                        <td>yes</td>
                        @endfor
                    </tr>

                    @php
                        $counter++;
                    @endphp
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

the header row is displayed fine but the body rows just displayed the first and second column like this :
[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: `$i` is a reference to `$from` so modifying it will modify the `$from`. Use a [period](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period) though it's a much better API to work with for time periods with intervals. If you want to make this work then do `for ($i = clone $from; ...` in both cases

Comment: @apokryfos I solved it by saving modified $from and two in a new variables

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by saving modified $from and two in a new variables :

```
<table class="table" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>#</td>
                    <td>ناڤ</td>
                   @for ($i = $from1; $i <= $to1; $i->modify('+1 day'))
                        @php
                            $date =$i->format('m/d');
                        @endphp
                        <td>{{$date}}</td>
                       
                    @endfor
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @php
                    $counter=1;
                @endphp
                @foreach ($students as $student)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$counter}}</td>
                        <td>{{$student->name}}</td>
                        @php
                            $new_from = Carbon::parse($from);
                            $new_to = Carbon::parse($to);
                        @endphp
                        @for ($j = $new_from; $j <= $new_to; $j->modify('+1 day'))
                            <td>{{$i->format('m/d')}}</td>
                        @endfor
                    </tr>

                    @php
                        $counter++;
                    @endphp
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```